# Set width of menu widget using Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-2.7, drop-down-menu

Using Python 2.7 and the Tkinter module, I have created a menubutton and assigned a menu to it. Now every time I post the menu in the specific location, the width of the menu is set automatically based on number of characters. Is there a way to set a static width in the menu widget?

The standard things I tried (such as the following) did not work.

```
self.menuwidget.config(width=80)
```

Comment: `self.mb  =  Menubutton ( self, text="something", relief=RAISED , width=100)` you could do that but I guess you mean the size of the checkbuttons...

Comment: I am having the same issue, however its not the button width but the width of the actual drop down menu

Comment: Yeah, that I don't know, sorry! But I'll take a look...

Comment: Thanks anyways Trufa, let me know if you come up with something, for now ill just pad each string with spaces :/

Comment: I will! That's a pity that you have to do that, but unfortunately tkinter's documentation is far from good/complete.

Comment: @Trufa et al.: if you want definitive documentation, consider reading http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm. Tkinter is based on tk, and it takes but a small mental translation to go from the tcl-based documentation to tkinter (eg: `.widget configure ...` becomes `widget.configure(...)`, etc). The tk documentation is fairly extensive. You can also get good information from http://www.tkdocs.com

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks! it has been a little since I don't have to work with tkinter but I'll sure check it out!! Thank for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to set the width of the menu.

Comment: That's a pity, so would you recommend what OP did (adding spaces/tabs at the end of the screen) or is there another workaround or maybe an alternative way to do with a similar result?

Comment: I tried for few days to figure it out, you could possible just pad each string or one of the strings. Thanks for the answer Bryan